# i and f are not variables. Storing variable into string

Tags: python

below is a portion of code where data is read from an excel file and is transferred into a `psspy` function. I am receiving an error about `_i`
and `_f`  not being variables. But I received this code by running an ibdev on `PSSE`. Is there any way to change this so the error is eliminated. I tried using the API's default variables but it didn't work as well. Also for the third element in the array, I'm trying to put a variable into a string so it can loop through multiple characters in my excel sheet. Is that the correct way of doing it? Attached are the API's for this particular function and capability.[image: API 1][image: API 2][image: API 3]

```
    for row in data:
    data_location, year_link, from_, to, max_value, min_value,digit = row[5:12]
    output = 'From Bus #: {}\tTo Bus #: {}\tVMAX: {} pu\tVMIN: {} pu\t'
      if year_link == year and data_location == location:
         print(output.format(from_, to, max_value, min_value))

         psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,'%s'%digit,[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
```

Comment: Try assigning i and f to a value

Comment: I can't. those values must stay untouched. some of the values are different for  each element of the array

Comment: If the values are different, you need to actually provide different values. They're inputs to your function and you haven't defined them

Answer (score 0):

The _i, _f, and _s are placeholders for default int, float, and string values, respectively. The PSSE API doc doesn't do a great job at clarifying this, but these default values will allow you to customize specific function parameters without needing to assign a value for each parameter.

The simplest solution is to import the following:

```
from psspy import _i
from psspy import _f
from psspy import _s
```

Alternatively, you can add the following lines:

```
for row in data:
    data_location, year_link, from_, to, max_value, min_value,digit = row[5:12]
    output = 'From Bus #: {}\tTo Bus #: {}\tVMAX: {} pu\tVMIN: {} pu\t'
      if year_link == year and data_location == location:
         print(output.format(from_, to, max_value, min_value))
         _i = psspy.getdefaultint()
         _f = psspy.getdefaultreal()
         psspy.two_winding_chng_4(from_,to,'%s'%digit,[_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i,_i],[_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f,_f, max_value, min_value,_f,_f,_f],[])
```

I don't know the call for _s, but that is rarely used in the API functions. Hope this helps.

Comment: `_s = psspy.getdefaultchar()` which is used for strings such as Bus name or circuit id